# Solving a simple equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a simple equation

```
$Assumptions = 0 < v < 1 && x ∈ Reals && v ∈ Reals;
eqn1 = v == 1 - (1 - x)^(3/2)
sol = Solve[eqn1, {x},Reals]
```

[image]

But if I do a few more steps by hand

```
eqn2 = (1 - v)^(2/3) == ((1 - x)^(3/2))^(2/3) // PowerExpand
mySol = Solve[eqn2, {x}]
```

[image]

Did I miss some assumptions or something else? The assumtions from above don't seem to affect `Solve`, only the domain parameter.

I know that this is not a proof!

```
Plot[{x /. mySol, x /. sol}, {v, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Line, Dashed}]
```

[image]

Comment: What are your assumptions on `v`? *Mathematica* assumes every variable is complex unless told otherwise.

Comment: What about this `Solve[eqn1, x, Reals] // ToRadicals // First `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you just want to avoid the complex roots, so,

```
eqn1 = v == 1 - (1 - x)^(3/2)
sol = Solve[eqn1, x, Reals] // ToRadicals // First // Simplify // 
PowerExpand // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Normal[sol]
```

[image]